# Issues Retrieving REP tokens

Tags: ether, augur

So I'm trying to retrieve my REP tokens, yet the JSON key backup that I pull out of my library/ethereum/keystore folder throws an error in the Javascript console saying "your key is not the proper length". Can anybody help me?

Comment: Are you using Parity? There is an outstanding bug where Parity does not recognise a small number of keys that are valid in `geth`.

Comment: This is the Parity issue - https://github.com/ethcore/parity/issues/2263 and https://github.com/ethcore/parity/issues/2268 .